# Which of the following are examples of Kantian noumena?

Tags: kant, history-of-philosophy, noumenon

> Which of the following are examples of Kantian noumena?
>
> a) Higgs boson particle
> b) A table
> c) A newly discovered planet
> d) All and none of the above

[Mel Thompson - Philosophy in a week]

The answer written at the back of the book is d. But I don't understand why answer is d. Answer d seems to have two sides: "All of the above" and "none of the above". I can understand the latter but not the former, please help me!

Comment: By definition, it is impossible to know the noumenon (we can't even know if it has parts, that is, objects; _thing-in-itself_ does not mean a direct correspondence between a physical thing and a portion of the noumenon). Your examples are either phenomena (when physical) or ideals (when rational). "_All and none of_..." is an oxymoron. _Philosophy in a week_ is not the same as Philosophy.

Answer (score 1):

1. It's all of the above, because any object is a noumenon, an object of thought but not of experience, if we abstract from our specific forms of sensibility - time and space. An appearance (or: phenomenon) is a noumenon *as it appears to us in experience*, so it's another aspect of this noumenon.
2. It's none of above, because, as empirical appearances, that is: as objects that we know empirically to be planets, tables, bosons etc. they're not noumena, because to consider them as noumena means to abstract from the forms of sensibility (space and time) which make their presence in experience, and thus classifying them under such concepts, possible.

If you're interested in learning more about this, you can read the *Preface* to the second ("B") edition of the *Critique of Pure Reason*  where Kant explains the necessity of the distinction and its nature. It's quite short, albeit Kant isn't the clearest writer.

Comment: Your #1 makes no sense. None of the listed things are noumena.

Comment: @DavidGudeman How does it make no sense? Perhaps it's not strict, but it follows Kant's own discussion in the *Preface* to the second edition of the first *Critique* and the *Analytic of Principles* section on the distinction. I think you don't understand the purpose of my answer, though. I was trying to make sense of why the author formulated the answer in this odd way.

Comment: Can you give a quote from the preface?

Comment: @DavidGudeman "the distinction, which our Critique has shown to be necessary, between things **as** objects of experience and those same things **as** things in themselves"  (Bxxvii)

Comment: I mean a quote where he says that an object of thought can be a noumenon. My understand of Kant is that he denied that noumena can be objects of thought.

Comment: @DavidGudeman They cannot be objects of *knowledge* but can definitely be *thought*. That's where the name "noumenon" comes from anyway - "nous" is "mind"/"thought". They're objects of mere thought, but not of knowledge. But, sure, here's a passage, also from the *Preface* to B edition of the *Critique*, that immediately comes to mind: "[...] on the one side as objects of the senses and the understanding for experience, and **on the other side as objects that are merely thought at most for isolated reason striving beyond the bounds of experience**". (Bxix)

Comment: OK, that's an important distinction, but one part of not having knowledge of noumena is that we can't even know they exist, so we have no knowledge that any such noumena as a Higgs bosun, a table, or a newly discovered planet exist, only that they exist as objects of experience.

Comment: @DavidGudeman We know anything of things as far as they're objects of experience so I don't understand your point there and how is that incompatible with anything that I said in my original post you objected to.